# remove InputObject label from output

Tags: powershell

There is an array, $a, that contains file names and is being outputted to a log file by this line of code -

```psh
$a | Format-List InputObject | Out-File $log -Append
```

The output looks like this -
[image]

The question is, how can the "InputObject : " labels be excluded from the output?

Comment: Have you tried removing `Format-List` from the equation? `$a |Out-File $log -Append` or `$a |Select -Expand InputObject |Out-File $log -Append`

Comment: The later worked best: $a |Select -Expand InputObject |Out-File $log -Append